# How to make Cardlibs CardView look exactly like Android Support CardView

Tags: java, xml, android-cardview, cardslib

I am using the `it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView` for it's adapter and control over the list of cards.

`it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView` looks terrible and adds padding and margin in places that are very annoying.

How do I make `it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView` and `it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView` look **exactly** like the default `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`?

(It's possible because it is somehow done in the demo `cardlib` app.

**fragment_cards.xml**

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**test_card.xml**

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    style="@style/card.native"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are using the "old" *CardView* tag.

With the version 2.x you have a new view called

```
it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative
```

You can find all info about migration [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/MIGRATE.md).

Also I provided a large documentation about [cards](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/CUSTOMIZATION.md).

Finally the demo app is open source and you can find it [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/tree/master/demo/stock).